# What is wrong with neo4j-shell traversal with command (trav -c)

Tags: shell, neo4j, graph-traversal

I am trying to traversal over graph nodes, and execute some command for each node. Like this:

```
neo4j-sh (0)$ trav -d 2 -c "ls $i"
```

But I always get the error:

```
Thread[...] already has a transaction bound
```

What is wrong? Is it a Neo4j bug?

Answer (score 0):

it's a bug and a sign that one one used this command for at least 2 years :)

you can run the equivalent cypher:

```
WITH {self} as n
MATCH (n)-[*2]-(m)
RETURN m;
```

Comment: Michael, my initial goal was -- to calculate the size of component of my graph and estimate its diameter. I expected to do this with the command like this:
`trav -o BREADTH_FIRST -c "set compId 1; set dist $pathLength;"`
Then I suppose that `max(dist) <= componentDiameter <= 2*max(dist)`
Can you advise me, how can I make such computations without Java-programming on traversal framework?